# X11 forwarding works for Firefox but fails for Chromium: Unsupported authorisation protocol

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I use MobaXterm to ssh into a Ubuntu20.04 machine, on which I launch firefox without problem but when I start chromium, it shows this error:
MoTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
[455878:455878:0417/171145.895062:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[455878:455878:0417/171145.895170:ERROR:env.cc(225)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.

I also tried Putty, same behavior. Firefox worked fine but chromium failed. In Putty the message doesn't show the "Unsupported authorisation protocol" line though.

Where do I set this auth protocol? And how do I see which protocol Chromium was trying to use but not supported?