# X11 fails to forward chromium-browser by the error "MoTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol", but I can launch XEyes

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, ssh, xorg

Title.

Simply running:

```
 chromium-browser --use-gl=swiftshader
```

Causes:

```
MoTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
[34006:34006:0305/101905.803733:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(238)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[34006:34006:0305/101905.803814:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

but when I run xeyes, it just, launches.

[image: launch]

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, ARM64,MobaXTerm, some random EC2 instance.

Thank you.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1716752/x11-forwarding-works-for-firefox-but-fails-for-chromium-unsupported-authorisati This fellow was probably encountering same issue.

Comment: See if [this article](https://chadrick-kwag.net/x11-proxy-unsupported-authorisation-protocol-error-fix/) applies to your problem. It basically fixes the locking of `.Xauthority`. If you're using SSH, try `ssh -X user@hostname`.

Comment: @harrymc I cant see the lock files, neither the .Xauthority from ls. .Xauthority exists, but I cant see it.

Comment: Have you used `ls -a` ?

Comment: @harrymc lock files doesnt exists and -X didnt help :(

Comment: Try also `ssh username@hostname -Y`.

Comment: @harrymc it didnt help too. welp :( thanks anyways.

Comment: What is $DISPLAY set to? Has `xauth` been installed?

Comment: @Bib DISPLAY: localhost:14.0: xauth and everything is installed with MobaXterm